# Finite quotient space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let X be a Finite space and  X/~ be a quotient space defined on X by some equivalent relation 
 and let p: X → X/~ be the quotient map .If Ux is the minimal basic open set at x  in X what will be the be minimal basic open set in the quotient space for the image of ??
does Up(x)=[x] will be the equivalent class of x

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that by "minimal basic open set at $x$" you mean the intersection of all open sets containing $x$, which is then open and is the smallest neighborhood of $x$.

Let's assume that $q:X\to Y$ is a quotient map between finite spaces. For every $x\in X$ define $U_x=\bigcap\{U\text{ open}\mid x\in U\}$. Similarly 
$V_y=\bigcap\{V\text{ open}\mid y\in V\}$ for $y\in Y$. As you know, the open sets in $Y$ are just the images of saturated open sets in $U$. So
$$V_y=\bigcap\{V\text{ open}\mid y\in V\}
=\bigcap\{q(U)\mid x\in U, U\text{ saturated & open}\}=
q\left(\bigcap\{U\mid x\in U, U\text{ saturated & open}\}\right)$$
Here we can choose any $x$ so that $q(x)=y$. Note that image and intersection commute since all $U$'s are saturated.

However, this $V_y$ need not be the image of $U_x$ for any $x\mapsto y$. Take for example $$X=\{a,b,c,d\},\ \tau=\{\varnothing,X,\{a,b,c,\},\{c\},\{c,d\}\}$$ $$q(a)=u, q(b)=q(c)=v, q(d)=w$$
Then $U_d=\{c,d\}$ but $V_w=q(X)=Y\ne q(U_d)$